# Cannot find where my site is being cached!

Tags: cache, nginx, cloudflare, cache-control

So I have a bit of experience as a web master, but am at my whits end trying to find out what is caching my site. I cannot see any updates I make for the life of me.

What I've tried:

- Clear Application Storage in Chrome Dev tools
- Purged Cache in Cloudflare Dashboard
- Enabled Dev Mode in Cloudflare Dashboard
- Double checked that it is being pulled from the network in chrome dev tools - it is.
- Added the following settings / headers to my nginx server config:

  > ```
  >    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
  >    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
  >    if_modified_since off;
  >    expires off;
  >    etag off;
  >    proxy_no_cache 1;    
  >    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
  > ```

I also have disabled the proxying/caching through cloudflare completely now.

I've tried renaming my index page to index2.php, for example - and then I am served the brand new version. So I am sure I am working in the correct directory, etc.

Any other hints as to what could possibly be caching my page?

I am not running Varnish or Squid or anything like that.

**EDIT:** I have tried copying and creating a new web root directory. That worked once, but then that version was also cached somewhere and can no longer be updated.

**EDIT2:** Okay so its definitely server-side somewhere, and not nginx - what else could be caching it there? Like I said I'm not running any sort of Squid or Varnish type proxy or anything.

Comment: How do you know that your site is being cached? Are you trying to make changes to the website that don't appear to be taking effect?

Comment: Application storage is not the same thing a your browser's cache.   Have you tried clearing the browser cache?   Have you tried multiple web browsers?   Have you tried from a different computer?    Trying those things would tell if you if it were being cached locally by your browser or if were server side.

Comment: Correct, change I make are not visible. I have also tried different browsers and devices and the changes are not visible on any of them. It is definitely server side, or rather not-client side. I think I've ruled out most things server side as well, I think it might be somewhere in between i.e. Cloudflare or something similar.

Comment: I'm glad you found where you problem was, but I have closed the question as "too broad."   There are many places that might be caching and your particular solution is unlikely to be the solution for the next person with a similar question.

Comment: Fair enough. I added another edit to try to make it a bit more specific, but if that's not enough you can just keep it closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it! Figured I'd post my answer here in case someone stumbles upon this thread later..

So in my case it happened to be opcache! I just added my webroot to the blacklist at `/etc/php.d/opcache-default.blacklist` and restart php-fpm and all was good!